# Choice of Prior

Tags: bayesian, prior

What should be the appropriate prior in case of a dummy variable and an interest rate variable which has values like 4.5, 4.6, 4.9 etc in a Bayesian linear regression?

Comment: Hi, first I think you have to inform us which is the dependent and independent variables, as well with the range of values that they take any correlations that you might expect between them, etc.

Comment: What is your situation? What have you considered? Which of the options typically proposed (e.g. see [here](https://github.com/stan-dev/stan/wiki/Prior-Choice-Recommendations)) seem appealing (are you trying to use as much prior knowledge as possible, as little as possible, an "uncontroversial" amount, do you want to base it on some other data, can you elicit opinions from experts etc.?)?

Comment: The dependent variable is Leads.